# how to make pointers to a member-function of a derived class

Tags: c++, class, function-pointers

I need to have array of function pointers in base class, and to define this array to point to functions in child classes like this:

```
typedef double (_f)(int,int);
class A{
public:
  _f **m_arf;
};

class B:public A{
public:
  double get1(int i, int j) {return i+j};
  double get2(int i, int j) {return i-j};
B(){
     m_arf = new _f*[2];
     m_arf[0] = &get1;
     m_arf[1] = &get2;
   };
};
```

and then I can do the following:

```
{
  A* pA = new B;
  int ires = pA->m_arf[0](1,2); // returns B::get1(1,2)
  int ires1 = pA->m_arf[1](1,2); // returns B::get2(1,2)
}
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Spooky ... [Watch out](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)! BTW, have you tried it? What did the compiler say? Which compiler was it?

Comment: I thought this is what virtual class members are for.

Comment: @RichardChambers:  There are still uses for function pointers.

Comment: @JohnDibling, yes there are uses for function pointers I just question whether this is one of them.

Comment: @RichardChambers:  Right, I simply assumed OP was simply trying to figure out how to implement a jump table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pointer:

```
typedef double (_f)(int,int);
```

Does not/cannot point to a *member function*.  It can only point to a *free function.*  So what you're trying to do will never work the way you're trying to do it.

To declare a member function pointer, the syntax is different:

```
typedef double (A::*_f)(int,int);
```

In addition, you also have to take the pointer with different syntax:  you must refer to the class.

```
_f = &B::get1; // not &get1
```

However, now you'll have another problem, and that is that `get1` isn't a member of `A`, but a member of `B`.  In order to assign a pointer to a member of a derived class to a pointer to a member of a base class, you must use `static_cast`:

```
m_arf[0] = static_cast <A::Fn> (&B::get1);
```

Finally, the syntax to atually call through this pointer is also different.  You can't just call through the pointer directly -- you have to also associate the call with an instance of the class.  The `->*` syntax connects the class instance to the function pointer:

```
int ires = (pA->*(pA->m_arf [0])) (1,2);
```

Phew, what a mess.  It's really best to not use member function pointers in this way unless you really have to.  Regardless, here's a demo of how it's done here.

```
class A{
public:
  typedef double (A::*Fn) (int, int);
  Fn *m_arf;
};

class B:public A{
public:
  double get1(int i, int j)  
  {
    return i+j;
  };  
  double get2(int i, int j)  
  {
    return i-j;
  };  
B(){
     m_arf = new Fn[2];
     m_arf[0] = static_cast <A::Fn> (&B::get1);
     m_arf[1] = static_cast <A::Fn> (&B::get2);
   };  
};

int main()
{
  A* pA = new B;
  int ires = (pA->*(pA->m_arf [0])) (1,2); // returns B::get1(1,2)
  int ires1 = (pA->*(pA->m_arf[1])) (1,2); // returns B::get2(1,2)
}
```